# What is the implication of a particular choice of $k(\epsilon)$ for the ABC Conjecture.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, abc-conjecture

Consider the $ABC$ conjecture in the following form:

For every positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a constant $k(\epsilon)$ such that for all triples $(a, b, c)$ of coprime positive integers, with $a + b = c$:

$c<k(\epsilon)\cdot rad(abc)^{1+\epsilon}$

Suppose I prove for a ***particular*** choice of $k(\epsilon)$ and ***any*** choice of $\epsilon>0$ that:

$c \ge k(\epsilon)\cdot rad(abc)^{1+\epsilon}$

What is the implication for the $ABC$ conjecture?

Comment: This proves effectively nothing. The "magic" of the ABC conjecture surrounds the universality of the existence **for every** $\epsilon >0$ of a **particular** $k(\epsilon )$ satisfying the inequality of the conjecture. Taking a specific $k(\epsilon )$ is a non-sequitur. It would be akin to fixing a specific $\delta$ in traditional $\epsilon -\delta$ proofs-- it's not the train of the thought that the ordering of $\forall$ and $\exists$ symbols demand.

Comment: ABC is of the form, "for every e there exists k such that P". Your question is about "there exists k such that for every e not-P". Just thinking through the logic, establishing your sentence can't tell us anything about the ABC sentence.

Comment: Isn't it at least a lower bound?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that I understand exactly what it is you are asking, but there are definitely interesting applications to knowing the ABC conjecture for particular values of $\epsilon, k(\epsilon)$.

To illustrate one such application, suppose that the ABC conjecture holds with $\epsilon=k(\epsilon)=1$. Then for all triples $(a,b,c)$ of relatively prime integers with $a+b=c$ we would have $$c\leq \left(\prod_{p\mid abc} p\right)^2.$$

Now suppose that $x,y,z$ are positive, relatively prime integers such that $x^n+y^n=z^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer. If we let $a=x^n, b=y^n, c=z^n$ then $$z^n=c\leq \mathrm{rad}(abc)^2 = \mathrm{rad}(xyz)^2 \leq (xyz)^2 < z^6.$$
Thus we've shown that $n<6$ and consequently that Fermat's Last Theorem holds for all $n\geq 6$.